# How to do SQL query for the most prescribed generic medication name

Tags: sql

For this assignment, use the following database schema:

a) Patient—PatientID, Name, DOB
b) Doctor—DoctorID, Name, MedLicenseNumber, Phone
c) Medication—MedicationID, BrandName, GenericName
d) Prescription—PrescriptionID, Date, PatientID, PrescriberID, MedicationID

The problem is asking to specify SQL query on:
The most prescribed generic medication name.

I tried this query and I'm getting a syntax error

```
SELECT TOP COUNT GenericName
FROM Medication m INNER JOIN
     Prescription p
     ON m.MedicationID = p.MedicationID
GROUP BY GenericName
ORDER BY COUNT(PrescriptionID) DESC;
```

Comment: What is `TOP COUNT`?

Comment: TOP COUNT is a query that i saw used for this type of question. I'm new to learning SQL and that's why I'm seeking help from an expert.

Comment: Please tag your question with what database you are using, oracle SQL can have different syntax to SQL Server ect and can affect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(GenericName), GenericName
FROM Medication m INNER JOIN
     Prescription p
     ON m.MedicationID = p.MedicationID
GROUP BY GenericName
ORDER BY COUNT(PrescriptionID) DESC;
```